# 64bit環境でWindowsAPICodePackのTaskDialogにてTaskDialogCommandLinkを使用した場合例外が発生

Tags: windows, c#, .net

.NET 4.5 (C# 6.0)にてWindowsフォームアプリケーションを開発しています。
下記のライブラリを使用してTaskDialogを使用したところ、例外が発生します。

- Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.dll
- Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.dll

【例外の内容】

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): 
Dialog contents too complex.
System.OutOfMemoryException: Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program.
at Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs.NativeTaskDialog.NativeShow()
at Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs.TaskDialog.ShowCore()
```

【追記】
x64環境で64ビットモードで動作させた場合に例外が発生します。
Visual Studioにて32ビット優先にチェックを入れてコンパイルしたところ、正常に動作します。

Comment: 読みやすくするため[edit]しました。インデント4つでコードブロックとして表示できます (編集フォームの上にある `{}` ボタンでもok)

Answer (score 2):

Windows 8 では試せていませんが、Windows 8.1 + Visual Studio 2013の環境では動作しました。

C# 5.0と.NET 4.5です。

Windows Formアプリケーションを作成し、
nuGetパッケージマネージャーから
`Windows7APICodepack`を検索して無印とShellをインストールします。(これでCoreもインストールされ都合3つ入ります。)

プロジェクトにアプリケーションマニフェストファイルを追加し、追加されたファイルを開き、最後の方にコメントアウトされている、`Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls`(version="6.0.0.0")のdependencyのコメントアウトを解除して有効にします。

フォームにボタンを配置し、以下の様なイベントハンドラを設定して実行すればダイアログが表示されました。

```
void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var dialog = new TaskDialog();
    dialog.Caption = "cap";
    dialog.InstructionText = "inst";
    dialog.Text = "text";
    dialog.Icon = TaskDialogStandardIcon.Information;
    dialog.StandardButtons = TaskDialogStandardButtons.Ok;
    dialog.Show();
}
```

なお、そのままだとアイコンが表示されないようです(バグ？)、その時は以下の様にopenedで再代入してみてください。

```
void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var dialog = new TaskDialog();
    dialog.Caption = "cap";
    dialog.InstructionText = "inst";
    dialog.Text = "text";
    dialog.Icon = TaskDialogStandardIcon.Information;
    dialog.StandardButtons = TaskDialogStandardButtons.Ok;

    dialog.Opened += dialog_opened;
    dialog.Show();
}

void dialog_opened(object sender, EventArgs e) {
       TaskDialog taskDialog = sender as TaskDialog;
       taskDialog.Icon = taskDialog.Icon;
       taskDialog.InstructionText = taskDialog.InstructionText;
}
```

---

## 追記

新たにまっさらなWin8.1 Pro + VS2015プレビューと Win8.1 Pro を用意して確認してみました。

私が先に示したコードでは問題は起きませんでしたが、コメント欄で言っていた`TaskDialogCommandLink` を使用した場合、確かに再現します。これはWindowsAPICodePackの問題です。  
VS2015上でデバッグ実行した場合でも同様に発生しました。

[**本家SO**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059736/taskdialog-from-winapicodepack-does-not-work-on-net-4-0)で同様の問題が投稿されていました。

こちらにあるようにポインタを32bit限定にしているのが問題で、Overflow Exceptionが発生します。
これはMSの1.0.0でも1.1.0でも同様に発生します。

お使いの1.1.1でその例外(too complex)が発生する原因はわかりませんが、githubのコードを修正して64bit環境でもTaskDialogCommandLinkが動作するバージョンの作成方法を示したいと思います。

元々 http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack/ でコードが公開されていたようですが既に閉じられています。（逆に言えば公式の修正はもうないのかも？）  
なのでソースを取得します。お使いの1.1.1と思われる[**aybe/Windows-API-Code-Pack-1.1**](https://github.com/aybe/Windows-API-Code-Pack-1.1)のリポジトリのソースからダウンロードしました。

- Microsoft公式のソースではありません。
- .NET 4.5にアップグレードし、VS2015 Previewでコンパイルするための手順です。他の環境については説明しません。
- TaskDialogCommandLinkが動作するためだけの最小限のソース修正のみを行っています。
- ShellExtensionsプロジェクトは除外し、対応しません。
- 特に私はプルリクエストを出すつもりもありませんのでここでの内容をプルリしても結構です。

以上を踏まえた上で確認してください。

### 修正手順

#### プロジェクトのアップグレード

ソースをクローンまたはダウンロードし、`WindowsAPICodePack12.sln`のソリューションをVS2015 Preview開きます。オリジナルのソースも同梱されているようですので、そちらがお好みなら`source (original)`ディレクトリのzipを解凍して`WindowsAPICodePack10.sln`ソリューションから修正してください。

元々3.5ベースなので、3.5を導入していない環境ではアップグレードウィザードが発生します。そのまま4.5にアップグレードします。
3.5環境でも使いたいのであれば別の開発環境を用意するか、.NET 3.5をインストールしてください。

ShellExtensionsではインターフェースの参照エラーでいろいろとエラーが発生しますがそちらは今回参照しませんので対応しません。ソリューションから除外してください。

#### 参照の追加

Shellプロジェクトにおいて`ContentProperty` 属性がみつからないためコンパイルエラーが発生します。
ShellプロジェクトにSystem.Xaml名前空間を追加して解決します。

#### is Nullableの修正

VS2015(というかRoslyn？)では is の第二オペランドにNullableを指定できません。このため

`WindowsAPICodePack\Shell\PropertySystem\ShellProperty.cs`の205行目でコンパイルエラーが発生します。

この行がそもそも何をしているのかすこし不明なのですが（コード的には、`value is Nullable`がtrueなら、valueのHasValueプロパティを呼び出して、結果がfalseならnullだからnullと同じ処理をしようというコードに見えますが、Tがint?でも value is Nullable はtrueにはならないし、Tがtypeでvalueが typeof(int?) でもtrueにはならない）、
以下の様に修正しました。

```
// if (value is Nullable)
if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) != null) 
{   // when type of value T is Nullable-type ( Tがnullableなら ）
    Type t = typeof(T);
    PropertyInfo pi = t.GetProperty("HasValue");
    if (pi != null && value != null)
    {
```

205行目だけでなく、210行目のif文でもvalue != nullとしている事に注意してください(確認したらNullable型のvalueがnullだとその後GetValueで落ちたので）。else ifのブロックだけでもいいのではと思わないでもないですが。

#### 問題の箇所を修正

問題のエラーの原因箇所を修正します。

`WindowsAPICodePack\Core\Interop\TaskDialogs\NativeTaskDialog.cs`
の533行目 `AllocateAndMarshalButtons` メソッドのforeachの中でcurrentPtrを設定している部分

```
Marshal.StructureToPtr(button, currentPtr, false);
currentPtr = (IntPtr)((int)currentPtr + Marshal.SizeOf(button));
```

を以下に書き換えます（本家では64bit限定に修正されますが、両対応する修正にします）。

```
Marshal.StructureToPtr(button, currentPtr, false);
// currentPtr = (IntPtr)((int)currentPtr + Marshal.SizeOf(button));
if(IntPtr.Size == 4)
{
    currentPtr = (IntPtr)((int)currentPtr + Marshal.SizeOf(button));
}
else
{
    currentPtr = (IntPtr)(currentPtr.ToInt64() + Marshal.SizeOf(button));
}
```

4がマジックナンバーじゃんというツッコミがあるかもしれませんが、他箇所でも4とか8で判定している箇所があったので気にしません :-)

これでビルドすれば無事ビルドは完了すると思います。

#### 自分のソースの参照を変更する

nuGetのパッケージをアンインストールし、先ほどビルドしたアセンブリを参照設定で追加します。  
Shellの方(Debugビルドなら`WindowsAPICodePack\Shell\bin\Debug`)を見ればCoreも参照されていてアセンブリがいると思いますので、ここにある2つを追加します。

その後、 プラットフォームターゲット `AnyCPU`で32bit優先オフでもプラットフォームターゲット `x64`でも、AnyCPU+32bit優先、x86、どれでも動くと思います。

検証に使ったコード(ダイアログ表示部分)は以下の通りです。

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var commandLinkDialog = new TaskDialog();

        commandLinkDialog.Caption = "cap";
        commandLinkDialog.InstructionText = "inst";
        commandLinkDialog.Text = "How r u";

        var link = null as TaskDialogCommandLink;

        link = new TaskDialogCommandLink("fine", "I'm fine.");
        link.Click += (s, evt) => commandLinkDialog.Close();
        commandLinkDialog.Controls.Add(link);

        link = new TaskDialogCommandLink("sick", "I'm sick.");
        link.Click += (s, evt) => commandLinkDialog.Close();
        commandLinkDialog.Controls.Add(link);

        commandLinkDialog.Show();
    }
```

[image: 実行できている事とプロジェクトオプション]

一応確認はしたつもりですが、修正対象ソースの取得元を2,3回変えたのでなにかおかしなことがあれば指摘してください。

Comment: app.manifestにて、Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controlsの箇所を有効しました。  
しかし、64ビットプロセスとして動作させると、同じように例外が発生するようです。
恐らく64ビット用のcomctl32.dllが呼ばれず32ビット用が呼ばれてるように思えます。

Comment: @PITA さん 私の環境ではx64ビルドに変えても動作しているようです（元はAnyCPUの32bit優先モードでした）。気になるのは２点あって、１つはどのライブラリを導入しているかです。私は 回答に挙げたキーワードでヒットする３つですが、いくつか派生版がありますのでその場合は挙動が異なるかもしれません。ライブラリの入手方法も示してくれればこちらでも検証できます。あとC#は6ですか？6だとVS2015のTPなどから作成されているのでしょうか。 もう一つ気になっているのは実行方法で、これは普通にデバッグ開始やexeを実行していると思って良いですか？MSTestだとアプリケーションと関係なく32bitで起動する場合があるので。

Comment: WindowsAPICodePackは、nugetからCoreとShell導入しておりVer 1.1.1 です。  
開発環境は、VS2015 TPです。 
検証は、開発環境を導入していない別のPC(x64)にて実行しています。  
AnyCPUにて32ビット優先のチェックを外すと、例外が発生します。  
なお、TaskDialogでは、TaskDialogCommandLinkを使用しています。

Comment: @PITA さん、了解です。すぐにはできませんが私の方でも少し確認してみますね。

Comment: @PITA さん、コードを修正する形での対処方法を追記しました。

Comment: 上記の指摘箇所を修正したところ、x64環境においても問題なく、TaskDialogを使用できました。ありがとうございます。